# Firebase non fatal issues are not exported to BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics

I enabled BigQuery integration to export all crashlytics data to this storage. As stated in documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export#what-data-exported all fatal and non-fatal errors should be exported. But when I queried app table there were not non-fatal errors at all when crashlytics dashboard shows non-fatals. Should I configure something additionally to view such issues in BigQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed this statement in [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export#understanding_the_firebase_crashlytics_schema_in_bigquery):

> When you link Crashlytics with BigQuery, Firebase exports recent fatal and non-fatal crash events, including events from up to two days before the link, with the option to backfill up to ninety days.

All my non-fatal events happened more than 2 days ago, so that's why I didn't see them in BigQuery table.

Answer (score 1):

[Firebase status dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Crashlytics/20004) provides status information on the services that are part of Firebase. We can see, that Firebase Crashlytics is experiencing crash ingestion delay, what can cause your issue with non-fatals exceptions. Please, keep an eye on it.

Additionally, when a crash or non-fatal event occurs on a device, it is timestamped using the device's clock. If the clock is set back to i.e 2018, a crash that occurs now will have a timestamp from 2018. The queries are written in terms of `event_timestamp`, meaning that events for inaccurate clocks will be end up in the export.

Exports of data from Firebase to BigQuery could result in delayed (up to several days) processing. Because Crashlytics data is scheduled to be exported every 24 hours, if devices are offline when they crash and come online (and report the crash) after the daily export then the latest BigQuery data will not showcase this crash until the next day's export.

If it occurs that the crash ingestion delay will get resolved and when you found, that it's still not working in your case, I would suggest you to fill in bug report [here](https://firebase.google.com/support).